# Iterate over a union

Tags: angular, typescript

I have such enum/range:

`period: 'UTD' | 'EOM' | 'ETM'`

I want to iterate through all options in select:

```
<select
        class="custom-select"
        [value]="period"
        (change)="period=$event.target.value"
    >
        <ng-container *ngFor="let e of period">
            <option [value]="e" [selected]="e === period">
                {{ e }}
            </option>
        </ng-container>
    </select>
```

I need to get HTML  with option per available enum in period range:

UTD
EOM
ETM

How is that possible please?

Comment: What do you mean "enum/range"? That appears to be a [_string literal type_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), which won't exist at runtime.

Comment: yeah it is called union, I did not know that. So enum/range = union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) & [string literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) have no existence at runtime, therefor you can't iterate over them.

What you can do is : define your union like that

```
const Periods =  [ 'UTD' ,'EOM',  'ETM'] as const;
type Period = typeof Periods[number];
```

And you will be able to iterate over `Periods`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Matthieu Riegler's answer, it works. I had a little pain to put working in component so here is a whole sample:

```
const Periods = ['UTD', 'EOM', 'ETM'] as const;
type Period = typeof Periods[number];

@Component({
    selector: 'app-input-date',
    templateUrl: './input-date.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input-date.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class InputDateComponent implements OnInit,  Validator, ControlValueAccessor {
    
    period: Period;
    periods = Periods;
...
```

and in HTML:

```
<select
        class="custom-select"
        [value]="period"
        (change)="period=$event.target.value"
        [disabled]="disabled"
    >
        <ng-container *ngFor="let e of periods">
            <option [value]="e" [selected]="e === period">
                {{
```